# How to auto close batch file after executing powershell script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file to run a powershell script but I am unable to find a command to auto close the batch file after running it.

This is my batch file code:

powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C1.ps1

I tried the following code to auto close batch file but it wouldn't.

timeout 2 >nul
exit

move nul 2>&0

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Your batch file will terminate after the `powershell` call terminates, which in turn happens after the script file passed to `-File` terminates. is the script file not terminating? Is it designed to run indefinitely?

Comment: Batch scripts automatically close after every command in them finishes, so we'd need to know how you're calling the script and whether or not you're expecting the command prompt to close while the powershell window is running. Also, I'm very curious to know what you think `move nul 2>&0` does.

Comment: @mklement0 my powershell script is opening and closing a serial port but it seems to be in a infinite loop. How do I kill the powershell script after its being executed once?

[System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]
$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM8,9600,None,8,one
$port.open()
$port.WriteLine("'2'")
$port.ReadLine()
$port.Close()
exit

Comment: You script is waiting for a message from the other end of the serial port before closing : ReadLine();  If the other end of the serial port never send a message with a return at the end you will hang forever.

Comment: @jdweng but it won't return anything as its meant to just switch from one channel to the other channel. That code will trigger a switch to the other channel. Is there any other feasible code to kill off the process after running?

Comment: You need to use Asynchronous methods to be able to kill one process from another process.  You only have one synchronous process so the ReadLine() is blocking until data is returned.

Comment: Isn't `$port.WriteLine("'2'"` enough to make the switch? If you really need to kill the process, you can launch a [background job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs) and kill it after a timeout (all from inside PowerShell).

Comment: @mklement0 yes thank you so much for your help. It works now by just removing that line.